# Swift regexp to extract the pure link from a href

Tags: swift, regex, string

I can use a regexp which extract the "href='link'"

```
"href\\s*=\\s*[\"']([^\"']*)[\"']"
```

from the string

however i don't want to include the href='' part, just the result

the bellow regexp should work, but strangely doesn't

```
let input = "Some text with a <a href=\"http://example.com\">link</a>."
let pattern = "(?<=href\\s*=\\s*[\"'])[^\"']*(?=[\"'])"

if let range = input.range(of: pattern, options: .regularExpression) {
    let url = String(input[range])
    print("Found link: \(url)")
} else {
    print("No link found")
}
```

Here's an explanation of how the regex is SUPPOSE to works:

`(?<=href\s*=\s*['"])`: Positive lookbehind that checks for the presence of href= followed by any amount of whitespace and a single or double quote character. This ensures that we're only matching links that start with href= and are enclosed in quotes.

`[^'"]*`: Match any number of characters that are not single or double quotes. This will match the actual link.

`(?=['"])`: Positive lookahead that checks for the presence of a single or double quote character immediately following the link. This ensures that we only match the link and not any additional characters that may be present after it.

**Update:**

this works

```
(?<=href\\=['\"]).*?(?=['\"])
```

however i wasn't able to modify it for a case where there is space after or before =, like "href = 'link'"

Comment: What about this with the href value as capture group 1, ie rangeAt(1) : (?:href\s*=\s*['\"])(.*?)(?:['\"])

Comment: @JohnWilliams this returns href="http://example.com" so also the href part

Comment: That is the MATCH. Capturing GROUP 1 will not include the href=. See https://regex101.com/r/fgTdZO/1

Comment: i mean ok, but for some reason Swift returns href="example.com"

Answer (score 0):

Taking note of your update, here is one solution:

```
(?<=href)(?:\s*=\s*\\['\"])(.*?)(?=['\"])
```

This uses a non-capturing group for the = and \ and possible spaces there can be, so when using regex, returned group should only be the link inside.

I'm not very familiar with the language and available regex methods, but if returning the groups of a match is not possible, then what is left is taking this match, and programmatically split and remove anything before the first '"' in the string.

Comment: this doesn't work, at leas in Swift :(